# how to update a html-select without reload the page in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

I need to update one dropdwonlist without reload the page, I mean, I have a form where I add the elements that I need, then I have another form where I have the dropdownlist conected to my database but if I do not have the element I need to select, I have to add it from the other form, but the problem is that i need to reload the page in order to the dropdownlist show the new element then I loose the data I was typing.
I wish to know a way to update the dropdownlist without reload the page.
Im using php and mysqli my code is simple:

```html
<form action="edit_col_exe.php" method="post">
<p><label>Add Element:</label>
   <input autofocus type="text" name="elemnt" class="input" required />
</p>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Form2:

Select Element
   
    query("select * from Elements order by Element asc") or die("fail");
      echo "Select an option";
      while($reg=$con ->fetch_assoc()){
      echo "";
      echo $reg['Element'];
      }?>

I hope someone can help me!
regards!

Comment: You just use Ajax to reload elements without refreshing the page. There are a lot of examples online

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax (I prefer jQuery) and remove your form.

JS

```
function addElement(){
  // get new name
  var name = $("#newElementsName").val();
  // create ajax call
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "edit_col_exe.php", // URL to php script
    data: { // post data for php script (I use the data from your form (including the typo))
      elemnt: name,
      save: 'Save'
    },
    success: function(data){
      // this function will be called when php script run successful (HTTP-Status 2xx)
      // Clear the input filed
      $("#newElementsName").val('');
      // Add new name to dropdown
      $("#elements").append("<option>"+name+"</option>");
    }
  });  

}
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <p><label>Add Element:</label>
     <input autofocus type="text" id="newElementsName" class="input" required />
  </p>
  <table>
     <tr>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="addElement()">Save</button></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <select id="elements" size="1">
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem and I want to share with you my solution, its simple:

```js
setInterval(function(){
            $('#searchelement').load('addelements.php');
        });
```

```html
<p><label>Element</label>
     <select id="searchelement" name="element" required />
</option>
</select></p>
```

So everytime I add an element at 'addelements.php', I can search the new element in the select list.